# code formatter puts spaces around lines that contain :: - how to turn off

Tags: formatting, c++builder, c++builder-xe

The code formatter for Builder C++ does the following

before:

```
{
    std::string Name;             
    short          NumMeterChans; 
    eChannelGroups Type;          
    std::vector<short>Index;     
}
```

after:

```
{
    std::string Name;             

    short          NumMeterChans; 
    eChannelGroups Type;          

    std::vector<short>Index;     
}
```

What flag turns that off, I tried everything I could think of.  (and what side effects does that flag have?)

C++Builder XE

Answer (score 0):

The formatter settings are stored in config files. Try saving your configuration and comparing it to one of the default configurations and you may be able to figure out what you've changed to cause that behavior. You can load the config files in RAD Studio XE and use the built-in Compare tool (Edit > Compare).

On the Tools > Options > Formatter > Profiles and Status page. Save your current profile (call it Formatter_gbrandt.config).

The config files are located in:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<User>\Application Data\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0
```

I have used Formatter_Wide.config to format your sample and I do not see the effect you are seeing.